# Different ways to download Bootstrap to visual studio code

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Different ways to download Bootstrap to visual studio code? i tired downloading the
CDN. but i wanted to know if they are different ways i can do this as well?

```
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
rel="stylesheet" 
integrity="sha3841BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" 
crossorigin="anonymous">

<script   src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" 
integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" 
crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: RTFM: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/getting-started/download/

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask regarding open-ended questions.

Comment: Also, you don't download files _to an editor_. Here you're loading it into a web page.

Comment: Please take the [tour] to learn how this site works. "Thanks" comments are discouraged.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use cdn not need to download just copy and paste on your header but if you want to download it inistall npm and download bootstrap package but the best way to use bootstrap its cdn